# error code: "invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript "

Tags: c++, arrays

my compiler tell me this:

```
"prog.cpp:56:27: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
   temp_arr[match[depth][0]]+= 3;//condition 1 win/lose
```

all the while, this is my code thumbnail:

```
int match[10][2];
int team_num;

bool Solve_2(int depth, int n, array<int, 5> &scores)
{
    if(depth < team_num) {

        bool con1,con2,con3;//for combining the return value
        array<int, n> temp_arr = scores;//temp_arr declaration <- duplicate score[]

        temp_arr[match[depth][0]]+= 3;//condition 1 win/lose
        temp_arr[match[depth][1]]+= 0;
                        //^ the compiler tell me here's the problem
        con1 = Solve_2(depth+1,n,temp_arr);
        temp_arr[match[depth][0]]-= 3;//reset array to prior condition
        temp_arr[match[depth][1]]-= 0;


        temp_arr[match[depth][0]]+= 0;//comdition 2 lose/win
        temp_arr[match[depth][1]]+= 3;
        con2 = Solve_2(depth+1,n,temp_arr);
        temp_arr[match[depth][0]]-= 0;//reset array to prior condition
        temp_arr[match[depth][1]]-= 3;

        temp_arr[match[depth][0]]+= 1;//condition 3 tied
        temp_arr[match[depth][1]]+= 1;
        con3 = Solve_2(depth+1,n,temp_arr);
        temp_arr[match[depth][0]]-= 1;
        temp_arr[match[depth][1]]-= 1;

        return con1 || con2 || con3;
    } else {

        return CheckArr_2(n, scores);
    }

}
```

i know from some other question that is this one caused after incorrect array subscript, but i think it is already correct. can anyone help me? thanks a lot :)

Comment: `array<int, n>` looks like you're using `std::array`, but you can't have `n` (a runtime variable) as a template parameter, is it supposed to be `5` to match `scores`?

Comment: As @kmdreko wrote, `n` cannot be used as a template argument because those need to be known at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

A more complete error report looks like this:

```
<source>: In function 'bool Solve_2(int, int, std::array<int, 5>&)':
<source>:13:21: error: 'n' is not a constant expression
         array<int, n> temp_arr = scores;//temp_arr declaration <- duplicate score[]
                     ^
<source>:13:21: note: in template argument for type 'long unsigned int'
<source>:13:34: error: cannot convert 'std::array<int, 5>' to 'int' in initialization
         array<int, n> temp_arr = scores;//temp_arr declaration <- duplicate score[]
                                  ^~~~~~
<source>:15:33: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
         temp_arr[match[depth][0]]+= 3;//condition 1 win/lose
                                 ^
<source>:16:33: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
         temp_arr[match[depth][1]]+= 0;
                                 ^
... snip ...
```

The first error reports `array<int, n>` can't be deduced to a type because `n` is a runtime variable and can't be used as a *"constant expression"* needed for a template parameter.

Its wise to address the errors in-order since later errors may be caused by others. That is the case here; the other errors are simply from the compiler defaulting `temp_arr` to type `int`.

Comment: so template parameter must be a constant, yeah, i see. sorry just a newbie programmer :/